# Solve says my system of equations has no solution

Tags: system-variables

I got a system like this (just for example):

[image]

I need to get some of the variables expressed in a form like the following.

> `x == (z - z1) Tan[α1q - μ ] + x1`

Let's say that `x` and `σ` are required. I write the following code:

```
eq1 := (x - x1) == (z - z1) Tan[α1q - μ ]; 
eq2 := (x - x2) == (z - z2) Tan[α2q - μ ]; 
eq3 := (σ - σ1) + 2 σ1q Tan[ϕ] (α - α1) == γ (z - z1 - (x - x1) Tan[ϕ]); 
eq4 := (σ - σ2) + 2 σ2q Tan[ϕ] (α - α2) == γ (z - z2 - (x - x2) Tan[ϕ]); 
system1 := {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}; 
Solve[system1, x]
```

Evaluation gives me just `{}`. How to make this request correct?

UPD got different outputs in notebooks and none of them is what I really want.

[image]

Comment: the question is ill posed. You have four equations and so to satisfy all you will need to solve for four variables ( Pick any four that do not live inside the trig funcions and you should get a nice result )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MMM is being ingenuous. `Reduce` returns a rather complicated expression with a lot of conditionals (24 of them). It turns out that the equation for `x` is same under all the conditions. So I think I need to show a little more work than MMM did.

```
eq1 = (x - x1) == (z - z1) Tan[α1q - μ];
eq2 = (x - x2) == (z - z2) Tan[α2q - μ];
eq3 = (σ - σ1) + 2 σ1q Tan[ϕ] (α - α1) == γ (z - z1 - (x - x1) Tan[ϕ]);
eq4 = (σ - σ2) + 2 σ2q Tan[ϕ] (α - α2) == γ (z - z2 - (x - x2) Tan[ϕ]);
system1 = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4};
```

Note I do not use `:=` here. It is inappropriate.

```
xeqs = Cases[Reduce[system1, x], x == _, ∞] // Union
```

> `{x == x2 + z Tan[α2q - μ] - z2 Tan[α2q - μ]}`

This last shows that there is really only one solution, so what is wanted is

```
xeqs[[1]]
```

> `x == x2 + z Tan[α2q - μ] - z2 Tan[α2q - μ]`

Comment: Not getting this. The result only satisfies one equation and if we are happy with that there are four results obtained by solving each equation individually for `x`.

Answer (score 6):

Try `Reduce`

```
eq1 := (x - x1) == (z - z1) Tan[α1 q - μ];
eq2 := (x - x2) == (z - z2) Tan[α2 q - μ];
eq3 := (σ - σ1) + 
    2 σ1q Tan[ϕ] (α - α1) == γ (z - 
      z1 - (x - x1) Tan[ϕ]);
eq4 := (σ - σ2) + 
    2 σ2q Tan[ϕ] (α - α2) == γ (z - 
      z2 - (x - x2) Tan[ϕ]);
system1 := {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4};
Reduce[system1, x]
```

Learning from Pros is always helpful...

```
Reduce[system1, x] // Union // First
```

> x == x1 + z Tan[q α1 - μ] - z1 Tan[q α1 - μ]

```
Collect[%, Tan[q α1 - μ]]
```

> x == x1 + (z - z1) Tan[q α1 - μ]